# Origin of "animabus illis"

Tags: ecclesiastical-latin, christianity, grammarians

In the offertory of the requiem mass there occurs the phrase "*tu suscipe pro animabus illis quarum hodie memoriam facimus*". I understand that **animabus* is used instead of *animis*, because the latter could be a form of *animus* just as well as of *anima*, and the ambiguity in meaning was felt to be unacceptable in a place such as this.

Are there any other places where the form **animabus* occurs? Can one point to an earliest such occurrence, and an "inventor" of this grammatical innovation?

Comment: FWIW there's also filiabus for filiis to make feminine explicit. The same for deabus and equabus. I think it posts ecclesiastical Latin

Comment: Filiabus, at least, seems to be preclassical http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfilia

Comment: Animabus, per L&S, is ecclesiastical: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Danima probably by analogy to filiabus. I can recall a number of prayers using animabus, like the optional prayer for parents in the responsum: miserere clementer animabus parentum nostrorum, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *...abus* dative/ablative plural is a rare feature of the first declension that can in exceptional cases be traced back at least to classical Latin. For example, you will find Cicero saying ([Pro C. Rabirio perduellionis reo](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/rabirio.shtml)):

> ab Iove Optimo Maximo ceterisque **dis deabusque** immortalibus [...] pacem ac veniam peto

Clearly in this case Cicero uses the form to explicitly call upon *goddesses* and could not very well have said *dis disque*. (He could have said *dis utrius sexus* or something to that effect, but how does that sound?)

So medieval Christian authors arguably did not invent this form out of thin air, but they took a rare form and applied it to many new words. Other forms were *famulabus* (for example in the [*Oratio pro his, qui in coemeterio requiescunt*](https://books.google.de/books?id=3KXAMBRlzaQC&lpg=PR77&pg=PR77#v=onepage&q&f=false)) and *monachabus*. While these make sense to explicitly mention women (Who would have thought medieval Christians were pioneers of gender-inclusive language?), the same cannot be said of *ecclesiabus*, *villabus* and other forms, which are also found.

Comment: *Animabus* is actually fairly common before the medieval period: it's all over the place in the Vulgate, Augustine, and even Servius Honoratus.